# How to have a single line header

Tags: cms, header, home, magento-2.2.1

I want to have a single line header in my magento 2 site I'm using the default luma theme, can some one help me with this?

Comment: what do you want in that single line header?

Comment: @anirvan Could you please, explain more what exactly you tried and what you want achieve ?

Comment: I want the logo, categories, and the header links in a single line